# CSS Gradient Background Not Whole

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the whole background of my page gradient style, however, it looks like this instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/poG69.jpg

CSS:

```
#gradient {

  background: #00BFFF;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <!--        Reset CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../public/stylesheets/css_reset.css">
    <!--        Main CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../public/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>
<body id="gradient">
<p>Hello World!</p>
</body>


</html>
```

I realized that if I add `height: 880px;` or some size of height it will look like http://imgur.com/AkUdK3e which is how I want it to look. But is there a way to do it without setting `height`? I tried

`background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom,#086A87, #00BFFF);`

but it still look like the first link, unless I add `height`. And it's annoying to find the height of my page and I don't want to add any additional height as you can see I can scroll down in the 2nd picture. If adding `height` is the only way, what's a good way to define the height of my page so there's no additional scrolling to either up/down or left/right?

Thanks.

Comment: Set height of `body` and `html` to 100%. Body is normally as height a content. Means if you have content which fill about 50% of the page, the body is about 50% high.

Comment: `body: padding:0, margin:0` ? But the code works as is. http://jsfiddle.net/zLhcj894/ You are using a CSS reset...right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Meyer CSS reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to fill the body you can sett the css property:

```
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
```

This forces the size of the background to 100% of the view port.

If you dont want the background to repeat (like if the page scrolls):

```
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: If you don't want scrolling on your page you can set the `html {height: 100%; }`
or you can set the html and body to `overflow:hidden` but i wouldn't recommend it because it will cause a lot of issues on smaller screens and in general on your page.

Answer (score 3):

here is answer for you

http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/bNjzVb

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r48qr07v/1/)**

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #00BFFF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your css:

```
#gradient {
  background: #00BFFF;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #086A87, #00BFFF);
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```